# Is there a way for ssh connection other than default port 22?

Tags: ssh, robotframework

In my Robot Framework script, I am trying to log in to SSH with credentials

```
Login  ${rw_ssh_login}  ${rw_ssh_password}
```

Using the port number 31107 defined in my master.tsv file as `${rw_ssh_port}`

I am using `resource = master.tsv` in my `project.tsv` file.

I want it to connect to port 31107 as defined in master.tsv instead of the default port 22.

Can someone help me with the correct syntax ?

Answer (score 1):

You specify the port in the keyword [Open Connection](http://robotframework.org/SSHLibrary/SSHLibrary.html#Open%20Connection).
syntax

```
SSHLibrary.Open Connection    ${host_address}    port=${rw_ssh_port}
```